# Android Java color touch area on touch event in Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-widget, touch

I am new to android development and I was confused in how to implement a simple color around touch area when using a dialog. I tried using the TouchPaint.java sample from Android.com/references but could not get the methods to work Dialog.

Please help me with links or code snippets. I wanna color the area around a touch in a Dialog screen and make it redraw itself in the next touch event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int color = bitmap.getPixel((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getX());

                  RGB.setText(" R:"+Color.red(color)+" G:"+Color.green(color)+" B:"+Color.blue(color));
```